# Working with Highcharts using @ViewChildren

Tags: angular, highcharts

There is an example for how to use Highcharts (Basic Line Chart) in Angular 2: https://angular2highcomponents.azurewebsites.net/LineCharts/BasicLine

I want to know how to implement this dynamically, without knowing how many charts I will draw. Here's what I tried (and failed):

in my component.ts:

```
@ViewChildren('chart') components: QueryList<any>;
Highcharts.chart(this.components.toArray()[0].nativeElement, this.lineConfig); //with a legit lineConfig, of course
```

in my component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 placeholder2">
        <div #chart style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
      </div>
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I get this error because components array is not initilized but with viewChild, It wasn't a issue (as you can see in the example)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try several things, I'll group them all :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

export class YourClass, implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {
    ngOnInit() {
        Highcharts.chart(this.components.toArray()[0].nativeElement, this.lineConfig); //with a legit lineConfig, of course
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        Highcharts.chart(this.components.toArray()[0].nativeElement, this.lineConfig); //with a legit lineConfig, of course
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        Highcharts.chart(this.components.toArray()[0].nativeElement, this.lineConfig); //with a legit lineConfig, of course
    }
}
```

Try with `AfterViewChecked first, it should work.`

Comment: Unfortunately none of them worked. Especially when I tried AfterViewChecked, it got into an infinite loop :(

Comment: Can you then try in any of those, with a timeout ? Your problem is that it doesnt find the HTML element, thus not finding the `nativeElement` property. Either you don't get it correctly (but with a ViewChild ... It's hard), or it's not loaded when you try to get it.

Comment: I also tried the timeout, still didn't work. Will try version with the timeout different ways.